# Configure external HDD for use with multiple linux PCs

Tags: fedora, permissions, filesystems, users, automounting

I've got an external drive, and I'd like to have a linux partition on it. I formatted everything correctly on one machine with Fedora20 (I have one `ntfs` and one `ext4` partition), but when I plug it in my older machine with Fedora12, it doesn't automount the `ext4` partition. I have found a solution that involves putting something like the following in `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=0123-abcd  /media/MYEXTDISC  ext4  ...,umask=000,dmask=000,...
```

But this has two problems:

1. It doesn't help since the old machine with Fedora12 does not support `umask` and `dmask` for `ext4`.
2. I would have to do something like that on every linux computer I use, which is impossible, since some of them are at work where I can't modify `/etc/fstab`.

My idea was that the the filesystem could provide some option like "treat all non-root files as non-root files" or "give all non-root files the rights `666` or `777`. However, I don't know if this is possible with `ext4`. I can change the filesystem to anything linuxy, the HDD is empty at this moment.

Comment: with ext4 you use chmod and chown to set permissions and ownership.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Now tell me how to do it in such a way that I can plug&play the disk on any machine. Using `chmod` every time I want to do something doesn't seem to be a working option...

Comment: @tohecz I'm confused as to why you have the umask and dmask. what are you trying to do?

Comment: @strugee That's a solution I have found on the internet, but it doesn't help me on the older machine (which is the 1st issue listed). It might work on the newer one, but then the 2nd issue comes to play :-/ I basically want to have a unix partition so that I can move linux files without corrupting them completely (at least I'd like to keep the `x` flag.

Comment: @tohecz I don't think you need those mount options for automounting...

Comment: @strugee Well, automount mounts the device with `700` permissions and non-existant owner/group `1000`m which is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your problem is that each installation has a unique owner. Linux identifies users by number, or UID. You can see your user id with the `id` command:

```
$ id
```

At any rate, your first user on Fedora 20 has a UID of 1000, while Fedora 12 has a UID of 500.

You either need to relax the permissions, use a common group on each install, or use the same UID for your users.

It is possible you may be running into problems with selinux as Fedora 12 and Fedora 20 auto mount in very different locations. Check for selinux problems or set selinux in permissive mode.

With an ext4 partition, as you can see, you use `chown` and `chmod` to manage permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having a lot of issues with EXT4 perhaps you can format the partition as EXT3 instead. This should be supported on any of the distros you'll come across and Fedora 12 should be OK with this as well.

Also why do you need to worry about the filesystem type on this external drive? I would probably just make it a filesystem type that's supported across everything, even using NTFS should be fine, especially if you're just using it to shuttle data around.

Going forward I'd suggest taking the time and moving up from Fedora 12, if possible.

Comment: Both `ext3` and `ext4` are supported. But according to `man mount` (and my attempt with `ext4`), the options `umask` and `dmask` are invalid for both of them.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to upgrade, Fedora 12 is pretty old, isn't it?

Comment: I just upgraded from F14 and that was installed in 2009-2010 I believe. So yeah it's old. 8-)

Comment: @tohecz - I wasn't doubting that it wasn't supported, just that the level of support can be problematic. If I recall during my install of F14 it was giving you the option of either ext3/4 and I went w/ 4, but before that ext3 was the preferred FS b/c ext4 was still being stabilized. That was one of my rationals for delaying my migration from F10 to F14.

Comment: @strugee - congratulations you just pushed me over 50k, thanks!

Comment: @slm I'll see if using `ext3` would help. Well, the machine is (since yesterday) my "back-door" in case the new one fails at one moment...

Comment: @tohecz - I stayed on F14 until 3 weeks ago - so I completely understand, so migrating that box is just one idea in solving your problem. Put it at the bottom of the list, we can keep looking for other options.

Comment: @slm \o/ congratulations! I was going to say have fun with your new privileges that I assume you get but looks like those end at 20k...

Comment: @strugee - yeah I'd been meaning to ask Gilles if there are secret things but keep forgetting. I could see them hiding things but maybe not.